# Get data from dynamic ID for Chart.js

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax, chart.js

I have created a simple chart.js line graph that can produce plots when there is a static "url" provided (Ex. localhost/test/data.php). On data.php there is a string of data that looks like this:

```
[{"bdi":"4","date":"2018-07-11"},{"bdi":"1","date":"2018-07-21"},{"bdi":"5","date":"2018-07-21"},{"bdi":"34","date":"2018-07-21"},{"bdi":"34","date":"2018-07-21"},{"bdi":"3","date":"2018-07-22"},{"bdi":"2","date":"2018-07-23"},{"bdi":"12","date":"2018-07-23"},{"bdi":"3","date":"2018-07-24"},{"bdi":"2","date":"2018-07-25"},{"bdi":"12","date":"2018-07-30"},{"bdi":"3","date":"2018-07-30"},{"bdi":"4","date":"2018-07-30"},{"bdi":"11","date":"2018-07-30"}]
```

The code for data.php looks like this:

```html
<?php
//setting header to json
header('Content-Type: application/json');

//database
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'test');

//get connection
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if(!$mysqli){
 die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->error);
}

//query to get data from the table
$query = sprintf("SELECT treatment_log.bdi, treatment_log.date FROM treatment_log WHERE treatment_fk = 21 ORDER BY created_at");

//execute query
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

//loop through the returned data
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
 $data[] = $row;
}

//free memory associated with result
$result->close();

//close connection
$mysqli->close();

//now print the data
print json_encode($data); ?>
```

Notice that the treatment_fk is **21**. This means that the graph will be generated for this specific customer.

I wanted to make it so that every time you visit a cutomer.php page there will be a graph generated for that specific customer (According to their data). So I redid my coding for data.php. Instead I put the code into customer.php as a prepared statment where treatment_fk would be a variable:

```html
        <?php
        
  $cid = htmlentities ($_GET['customer_id']);      
//query to get data from the table
$sql = sprintf("SELECT treatment_log.bdi, treatment_log.date FROM treatment_log WHERE treatment_fk = ? ORDER BY created_at");

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $cid);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$data = array();
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $bdi, $date);
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
    $data[]['bdi'] = $bdi;
    $data[]['date'] = $date;
}
//free memory associated with result
$result->close();

//now print the data
print json_encode($data); ?>
```

So now, every time you visit a unique customer with different ID's (in the url) a different string of data will be generated on the customer.php page.

Now the issue that I am facing is that I cannot successfully generate the line graph based on this string of data (bdi vs date).

**Here is my code of the chart.js graphing field:**

```js
 
        $(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost/test/data.php",
  method: "GET",
  success: function(data) {
   console.log(data);
   var bdi = [];
   var date = [];

   for(var i in data) {
    date.push( data[i].date);
    bdi.push(data[i].bdi);
   }

   var chartdata = {
    labels: date,
    datasets : [
     {
      label: 'BDI',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(239, 243, 255, 0.75)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(84, 132, 255, 0.75)',
      hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
      hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        
      data: bdi
     }
    ]
   };

   var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

   var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: chartdata,
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
        legend: {
            position: 'bottom',
            
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    fontColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
                    fontStyle: "bold",
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    maxTicksLimit: 5,
                    padding: 20
                },
                gridLines: {
                    drawTicks: false,
                    drawBorder: false,
                    
                }
}],
            xAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                    zeroLineColor: "transparent",
                    display: false
                        },
                ticks: {
                    padding: 20,
                    fontColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
                    fontStyle: "bold"
                }
            }]
        },
                    
            tooltips: {
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255)',
                titleFontColor: 'rgb(184,189,201)',
                bodyFontColor: 'black',
                displayColors: false,
                borderColor: 'rgb(214,217,225)',
                borderWidth: 1,
                caretSize: 5,
                cornerRadius: 2,
                xPadding: 10,
                yPadding: 10
            }
        }
});
  },
  error: function(data) {
   console.log(data);
  }
 });
});
```

Notice that the URL is http://localhost/test/data.php. 
Although this does generate graph, it is not a graph specific to the customer. I have tried to replace the url with http://localhost/test/view_customer?customer_id=12&operation=edit (to test if a change in URL would work). However, it still does not generate a graph. Keep in mind that when I visit http://localhost/test/view_customer?customer_id=12&operation=edit in the source code, there is a string of data bdi vs. date. Regardless a graph is still not generated.

Here is my question:

**1. How do I make the URL dynamic so that I generates a graph based on the specific ID of the customer.php? (Is there a better way?)**

P.s. remember that http://localhost/test/view_customer?customer_id=12&operation=edit did not generated a graph when it was placed as the url in chart.js code.

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating the same type of array on customer.php as you are on data.php.  Replace your while loop in customers with the below and you should have the same format of JSON.

```html
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
  $data[] = array('bdi' => $bdi, 'date' => $date);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I just replaced my while loop with your suggestion. However, instead of getting a string of data, I got: [true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true]

Comment: I didn't see the bind_result, try again with updated code above.

Comment: Ah I see! Okay so right now the code you updated gave me [["1","2018-06-10"],["42","2018-06-06"], etc. However the format Im looking for is more the like, [{"bdi":"4","date":"2018-07-11"},{"bdi":"1","date":"2018-07-21"}, etc. Could you help generate this?

Comment: Perfect! So the formatting is now great! However, I'm still unable to generate the a graph even when I replace the URL with the current customer ID. Any Ideas?